# How to change the checkoutProvider name in magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping, magento2.3, countries

where we need to change the **'checkoutProvider'** name for passing custom countries list in magento2 checkout page. I tried to change in `checkout_index_index`.xml file but not working.
how to display in frontend checkout page.

```
$jsLayout['components']['checkoutProviderShip']['dictionaries'] = [
                    'country_id' => $this->getShipCountryOptions(),
                    'region_id' => $this->getRegionOptions(),
                ];
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Share here that you have tried.

Comment: yes. shared the code I modified the country data in code

Answer (score 0):

You can use plugin over `Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\DirectoryDataProcessor`

And create **after** plugin on method `process()` and modify this function output.

**Plugin class**

```
<?php
namespace Stackexchange\Magento\Plugin;

use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class DirectoryDataProcessorPlugin {
   /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $regionOptions;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\CollectionFactory
     */
    private $regionCollection;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\CollectionFactory $regionCollection,
    StoreManagerInterface $storeManager = null
    ) {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(StoreManagerInterface::class);
        $this->regionCollection = $regionCollection;
    }
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\DirectoryDataProcessor $subject,
        array $jsLayout
    ) {
        if (isset($jsLayout['components']['checkoutProvider']['dictionaries'])) {
            $jsLayout['components']['checkoutProvider']['dictionaries']['country_id'] = $this->getShipCountryOptions();
            $jsLayout['components']['checkoutProvider']['dictionaries']['region_id'] = $this->getRegionOptions();
        }
        return $jsLayout;
    }
    public function getShipCountryOptions()
    {
        // Write your code
    }
    private function getRegionOptions()
    {
        if (!isset($this->regionOptions)) {
            $this->regionOptions = $this->regionCollectionFactory->create()->addAllowedCountriesFilter(
                $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()
            )->toOptionArray();
        }

        return $this->regionOptions;
    }    
}
```

Comment: have using plugin or class rewrite??

Comment: use pluging is best solution

Comment: Only checkout.right>

Comment: if I use in the checkoutProvider data displaying fine but this is replacing the data so I'm using tha checkoutProviderShip but is not displaying in frontend

Comment: okay under your requirment

Comment: only for Shipping address?

Comment: I am litlle bit busy right now. Chat you after 30mins